# Custom TableViewCell as button without UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Trying to recognize a selection TableViewCell. They're static cells, not needing any scrolling. Do I need to implement the UITableView? Is there a way just to add actions to the TableViewCells without implementing the TableView and associate methods?

Comment: Static cells work only in UITableViewController, which already include the UITableView. If you don't want to use UITableView, why not just use UIButtons.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want or why you would want to do it without using a table view. But, if you implement a UITableViewController that controls a static table view, you don't have to implement any of the usual data source methods. You could just implement the delegate method, tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath:, and use that to provide the actions when you select a cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        //do some action;
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
        //do some other action;
    //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, so you can add it to any view as a subview. But UITableViewCell is designed to use in UITableView, you cannot make it work perfectly if you not use UITableView. Why not using a UITableView to contain the cells? You can set `tableview.scrollEnabled = NO;` to make it static.